# How to set title on node creation using token in action rule

Tags: nodes, rules, tokens

I've a action rule that add a node of type "profil". The aim is to set the title of that node to the author name (i've got fields for that...)

Here is an export of rules section do :

```
"DO" : [
  { "entity_create" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "node",
        "param_type" : "profil",
        "param_title" : "[account:field_identite:given] [account:field_identite:family]",
        "param_author" : [ "account" ]
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Entit\u00e9 cr\u00e9\u00e9e" } }
    }
```

The param title which i want to be composed by two fields ( given name + family) doesn't work. I've got an empty title at creation.

If i put only the given name it works, but export is different :

"param_title" : ["account:field_identite:given"],

Notice that the " are not in the same place (has if the token was recognized )

So i've tried to import :

"param_title" : ["account:field_identite:given"] ["account:field_identite:family"],

But i've got an error during importation process in rules.

Does someone knows hwo to have composed tokens ?

Any Help will be appreceated 
Thx

Comment: What kind of fields (text, image, etc.) are "given" and "family"?